# Spark SQL Java: best way to reverse a functions.posexplode

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I have a dataframe and I use:

```
df.select(
    df.col("id")
    sql.functions.posexplode(df.col("a")).as("pos", "a")
)
```

Then I make some transformation of "a" into "b", and I want to retrieve the original lists of "b". The best I have is something like this:

```
df.select(
    df.col("id"),
    functions.map(
        df.col("pos"),
        df.col("b")
    ).as("indexed")
).groupBy(df.col("id")).agg(
    functions.collect_list("indexed")
)
```

And then write a UDF to take the list of mapping elements and turn it back into a single list. Is there some way to avoid doing this by ordering the collect_list from the "pos" column?

Comment: You may be able to achieve this by sorting the frame in your desired order before groupBy so the input to groupBy is in the right order before it calls collect_list. Haven't tried but I think this should work.